# How can I find out reason for blank page of Symfony homepage?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the Symfony framework.
I assigned the `public` folder to my subdomain `project.mypage.com`
Now I only see a blank page.
If I instead assign the root folder of Symfony to my subdomain and go to `project.mypage.com/public` then I see my website! This is strange...

This is my index.php in the public folder:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// The check is to ensure we don't use .env in production
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.');
    }
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}

$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
$debug = (bool) ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== $env));

if ($debug) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts));
}

$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This is the last entry in my dev.log:

```
[2018-06-05 15:36:42] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"28c9ba","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://project.mypage.com/public/_wdt/38c9ba","method":"GET"} []
```

Comment: If you are clueless, trying echoing any value before and after your require('autoload') file, to check if the file is getting included or not.

Comment: @5eeker  I echo before and after `require("autoload")`. I get a blank page. But If I delete the code after until the end of the document, then I see the echoed values

Comment: I also tried to write `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the index.php. But the page is still blank

Comment: do echo('123);exit; before require, if it echoes... try 
echo('123'); require(); echo ("after"); exit; I think the issue is with your require ('autoload');

Comment: @5eeker I am also cofused. But the "exit" is not working. I have a blank page. Only when I remove the code after the echo, then I see "123"

Comment: Try commenting your require(); you will see errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your **require** statement. Check where is your **vendor** folder.

For ex: If your code file (below) is on the same directory level as vendor, you will not have to use `'..'` in require.

```
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Vice versa, if it is two or more levels inside a directory add the `'../..'` like so

Comment: I echoed `__DIR__`. It is `...www/project/public`

Comment: The vendor folder is in the root, this means in the same level then public www/project/vendor

Comment: yeah, if it is in the same level remove the two .. (dots) and / (backslash) it should work, check the require statement in my answer

Comment: I removed it, as recommended, but still a blank page :'(

Comment: Maybe I should not assign my website to the public folder... Because it works when I assign it to the root folder and go to project.mypage.com/public

Comment: You haven't done that, symfony reads the public directory at start to serve pages do that and check please

Comment: Ok, I found a working solution. I do not know if this is the best. I assigned the domain to the root folder. There I created a .htaccess file with this content `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project.mypage.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]` Now everyting is working fine